# Find the nearest postive definte matrix with Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am wanting to find the nearest positive definite matrix to some X matrix.

I have seen this answer here: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30631/how-to-find-the-nearest-a-near-positive-definite-from-a-given-matrix

But I am having trouble translating that to an answer in Eigen. I have tried the following:

```
Matrix<double, 9, 9> X, D, DPLUS, Z, Y;
X.setRandom();
Y = 0.5 * (X + X.transpose().eval());
EigenSolver<Matrix<double, 9, 9>> es;
es.compute(Y);
D = es.eigenvalues().asDiagonal();
DPlus = D.cwiseMax(0);
Z = es.eigenvectors() * DPLUS * es.eigenvectors().transpose().eval();
```

This is giving me errors about a complex problem, but is this inline with what the linked answer is suggesting?

Comment: Why did you stop after the first step in the answer?

Comment: @Aziuth I guess I'm not sure how to do the other parts, e.g. how would you get the Diagonal matrix from the eigendecompostion in step 2?

Comment: @Aziuth I edited the question following the steps, is that more inline?

Comment: If your matrix is symmetric use `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`. Otherwise, try: `DPlus = es.eigenvalues().real().cwiseMax(0).asDiagonal();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems that you're not using the right eigenvalue solver.

Since the matrix ***Y*** is symmetric by construction, you need to use `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`.
This symmetry guarantees that your real matrix is diagonalizable and has real eigenvalues and eigenvectors, so you don't have to deal with complex numbers.

The general `EigenSolver` doesn't make this assumption and thus isn't going to work as you intend in this case. You could get the same result with it (you'll get complex eigen values which are all going to be in fact reals, but you'll need to create vectors of complexes etc. Also it is much less efficient).

This will give you the eigen values and the eigen vectors which you can use to construct your orthogonal basis matrix ***Q***.

```
const MatrixXd Y = 0.5 * (X + X.transpose());
const SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> solver(Y);
const VectorXd D = solver.eigenvalues();
const MatrixXd Q = solver.eigenvectors();
const VectorXd Dplus = D.cwiseMax(0);
const MatrixXd Z = Q * Dplus.asDiagonal() * Q.transpose();
```

Of course if you like one-liners you can always shorten it to :

```
const SelfAdjointEigenSolver<MatrixXd> solver(0.5 * (X + X.transpose()));
const MatrixXd Z = solver.eigenvectors() * solver.eigenvalues().cwiseMax(0).asDiagonal() * solver.eigenvectors().transpose();
```